# How to upload an image to Amazon S3 using php webservice?

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am uploading an image to amazon S3 using php through webservice but it shows the following error:

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in and
Failed opening required 'Zend/Service/Amazon/Abstract.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/jltcnyc1/public_html/mydb/S3.php

```
require_once 'S3.php';
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3(secret_id,key);
$s3->createBucket("photos");
$file=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$s3->putObject("photos/", "file");
echo $s3->getObject("photos");
```

The file details are inserted into my db ok, but not to my S3.

Comment: You don't have Zend Framework installed. Or at least your script knows nothing about its location

Comment: @Suresh: Please re-generate your API key.

Comment: you are sharing your amazon S3 secret in the source-code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a path error and your 'Zend/Service/Amazon/Abstract.php' file is not being located.

In your S3.php file, you need to include the appropriate path location for 'Zend/Service/Amazon/Abstract.php' from your server root.

If Abstract.php is in your server root that code looks like this:

```
require_once 'Abstract.php';
```

Alternatively, if your S3.php is not in your server root, you can fix your `require_once` in your code above like this:

```
require_once 'path_to_zend/S3.php';
```

Comment: @tim peterson : iam using above two methods but the result is not change

Comment: @Suresh is S3.php in your server root directory?

Comment: Does this file exist on your server: `Zend/Service/Amazon/Abstract.php` and where is it in relation to your root? And where is that file called within S3.php?

Comment: @timpeterson:S3.php in mydb and abstract.php also in mydb

Comment: how is abstract.php referenced in your S3.php file? Is it like this: `require_once 'abstract.php';`?

Comment: @timpeterson:like this require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/Abstract.php';.

Comment: can you change that to `require_once 'Abstract.php';` and let me know what happens?

Comment: @timpeterson:same errror :::require_once(Zend/Service/Abstract.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jltcnyc1/public_html/mydb/Abstract.php on line 26

Comment: it looks like Abstract.php is in your mydb directory, but your public_html is actually your server root. I think this is an issue of where your Zend application root is relative to your server root

Comment: @timpeterson : has problem in S3.php i will download new S3 file its working